# XML Parsing Error: not well-formed, error trying to load GeoJSON

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, geojson

**UPDATE**: I opened the shapefile from which my GeoJSON file came using QGIS. I saved the layer as [this GeoJSON file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sgz93i4sb09lzhj/boundaries-projection-conversion-attempt.geojson?dl=0), making sure to select the projection `WGS84/EPSG:4326` when saving. But I still get the same error described below when I attempt to place the GeoJSON on a Google Maps layer. [The original shapefile is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxe47i5al6hklbk/cities.zip?dl=0).

I'm trying to add [this GeoJSON](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhdt7ayfols81lv/municipal%20boundaries.geojson?dl=0) to a map using Google Maps API.

My code.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initMap(){
            var map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById("map"),
                {
                    zoom: 9,
                    center: {lat: 26.6949358, lng: -80.3487426}
                }
            );
            map.data.loadGeoJson("path/to/city-boundaries.geojson")
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I open the HTML file in Firefox, I see the following error in the developer's console.

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: file:///path/to/city-boundaries.geojson
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`loadGeoJson`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.loadGeoJson) uses XHR under the covers, it won't work with local files.  The files need to be served by a webserver.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.loadGeoJson):

> **loadGeoJson(url[, options, callback])**
>   Parameters: 
>   url:  string
>   options:  Data.GeoJsonOptions optional
>   callback:  function(Array) optional
>   Return Value:  None
>   Loads GeoJSON from a URL, and adds the features to the collection.
>
> **NOTE:** The GeoJSON is fetched using XHR, and may not work cross-domain. If you have issues, we recommend you fetch the GeoJSON using your choice of AJAX library, and then call addGeoJson().